# How to update a doc string in python files programatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, docutils

I have a bunch(approx 23) of .py files present in the same folder and a approx a total of 50 + functions present in each file and the respective doc strings have been updated into a csv or text file 
Are there any documentation utility or python packages  which will help  to update the doc strings in these python file programatically ?

Answer (score -1):

Python is quite good for documentation/testing framework.

One very cool, is the 'readthedocs' framework.

Install sphinx

```py
pip install sphinx
```

and init a new docs folder project

```sh
mkdir docs
cd $_
sphinx-quickstart
```

Once done you will be able to create the documentation by run the make command into that folder

```sh
make html
```

Now you can manually modify the doc.
Here the detailed steps

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html

If you want to custom replace a single word in a lot of file, you will risk to break your code.
No sed/grep combination will be helpful here.

Instead you have to make a python script that filter only the comment text (# and """) and update the word